# PHP 7.0 mktime not working

Tags: php

getting months using mktime not working in PHP 7.0.

```
    $month_options="";
    for( $i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++ ) {
        $month_num = str_pad( $i, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT );
        $month_name = date( 'F', mktime( 0, 0, 0, $i + 1, 0, 0, 0 ));
        $selected="";
        $month_options.$month_name."<br/>";
    }
    echo $month_options;
```

**Result in PHP 5.5**

```
January
February
March
April
May
June
July
August
September
October
November
December
```

**Result in 7.0**

```
January
January
January
January
January
January
January
January
January
January
January
```

please help me how to reslove this issue?..thanks in advance

Comment: what is the use of $month_num ? and why do you make $i+1 in mktime ?

Comment: its not in use i forget to comment that line..sorry

Comment: as per docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php *"is_dst parameter has been removed."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is cleary written [**here**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) that last parameter `is_dst` of [**mktime**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) has been removed in PHP 7, You have to give 6 parameters instead of 7.

[**Try this code snippet here 7.0.8**](https://eval.in/783706)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$month_options = "";
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++)
{
    $month_num = str_pad($i, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $month_name = date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i + 1, 0, 0));
    $selected = "";
    $month_options .= $month_name . "<br/>";
}
echo $month_options;
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use DateTime objects instead? They are easier to work with, and easier to manipulate. DateTime is available from PHP5.2 and upwards.

This snippet

```
$date = new DateTime("january");
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    echo $date->format("F")."\n";
    $date->modify("+1 months");
}
```

would output

```
January
February
March
April
May
June
July
August
September
October
November
December
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/aeZIg)

Answer (score 1):

note PHP7 = is_dst parameter has been removed.

```
$month_options="";
for( $i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++ ) {
    /* $month_num = str_pad( $i, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT ); -- there is no use for this line */ 
    $month_name = date( 'F', mktime( 0, 0, 0, $i + 1, 0, 0)); // is_dst parameter has been removed.
    /* $selected=""; -- there is no use for this line */
    /* $month_options.$month_name."<br/>"; -- you are not correctly set this paramter */
    $month_options .= $month_name."<br/>"; // so if you do like this, it will be correct
}
echo $month_options;
```